# Java MapReduce by 2 fields into time slides

Tags: java, mapreduce

I have the following input:

```
{"start_time": 1, "end_time" 3, "app_name": "app1"}
{"start_time": 2, "end_time" 4, "app_name": "app2"}
{"start_time": 3, "end_time" 5, "app_name": "app1"}
{"start_time": 3, "end_time" 5, "app_name": "app2"}
{"start_time": 10, "end_time" 12, "app_name": "app1"}
{"start_time": 15, "end_time" 17, "app_name": "app2"}
```

I need to turn this input into time frames for each app?
output should look something like this:

```
{app1, [{1,5}, {10,12}, app2 [{2,5}, {15,17}]]
```

I thought about using mapreduce but I'm not sure how...
Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following is just one possible solution, not guaranteed to be the optimal.

**upd.**
[This is a demo I wrote for clarification. If people who see this have a better idea of improving, please tell me via github issues.](https://github.com/CJSHP/SparkLocalTest/blob/master/src/main/java/com/shp/app_reduce/MapReduceApp.java#L1)

At the very beginning, we can divide the question into three parts:

0. Consider map-reduce as returning a sequence of key-value results, what's the key in this question?
1. How to design the return type during the map part?
2. How to reduce when already mapped?

It goes without saying that the answer to the 0-th question is `app`. So, we divide the input into 2 parts, one for `app1`, and the other for `app2`. And we just look into one part, like `app2`, since this one is a little more complex than `app1`.

When designing the map function, we should notice that **the type must be good for reducing, meanwhile show the result naturally**. Considering the result, it is shown in the form of `List<Pair>`. So the answer to the 1st quesion is `List<Pair>`.

So, we use `mapToPair` to map every single line of input in the form of `(app, [(begin, end)])`. Then we just consider how to reduce.

Things become easier. The reduce process itself is a classical problem -- Interval Merging, to which the most classical solution is an `O(nlogn)` algorithm. But this question is another version, since when reducing, the list itself is naturally sorted on both sides. So the sort part can be omitted, thus lead to an `O(n+m)` one-pass merge-sort-like algorithm. Try applying this algorithm to `app2`, you'll make it.

The side effect is, too many `List`s are created, meanwhile `Pair`. One possible way is to use a mutable design, when leave out the redundant pairs, collect them properly, and when creating a new pair is needed, just use the collected ones.

Comment: Hello SHP. Can you please provide a code snippet which depicts your solution? Thank you!

Comment: @TamirM. Done, click the link in the answer above for detail.